Converting entity types in jpa within the same hierarchy given inheritance.joined
Suppose there are two entity classes MiscLineItem and LineItem where MiscLineItem LineItem extends MiscLineItem. The difference between the two is that LineItem maintains a non null association with an Item entity whereas MiscLineItem does not because by definition MiscLineItem does not associate with any Item entities...
Further suppose that MiscLineItem is annotated with @Inheritance( strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED )
Finally, both entities share the same sequence of autogenerated id's (Long in this case) so one sequence of id's can differentiate all MiscLineItem types depending on the table that they belong on.
Now here is the real question. Is it possible to convert one entity type to the other and vice versa?
Say the user made a mistake and persisted a MiscLineItem but meant to persist a LineItem. Ie the user goes into the LineItem form and passes an Item instance to the MiscLineItem id.
Or alternatively the user persisted a LineItem but meant to persist a MiscLineItem. Ie the user goes to the LineItem form and removes the Item association of the LineItem.
Now the server would have to recognize this entity type change and be able to convert one from the other. Since the MiscLineItem's share a singe id sequence and the tables for both entities are joined all we need to do is either add or delete the row from the LineItem table to support this kind of feature.
If the LineItem table has the id of the corresponding MiscLineItem then it's a LineItem otherwise it's a MiscLineItem. This is what @Inheritance( strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED ) enables.
Please note I am not using spring data and am implementing my own repos. I could go ahead and do my own sql statements to implement this kind of logic but I'm not sure if its viable or if there is a better/streamlined approach to this kind of feature...
